# Socket.io connects but does not receive message on the client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, eventemitter

I implemented the server and client with socket.io and the server is working correctly, when some client connects it logs me in, but when I emit an event it does not arrive at the client, it follows the code to analyze:

And the console.log from socket object it says this:

connected:false,
disconnected:true

Server:

```js
'use strict';

const chalk = require('chalk');
const _ = require('lodash');
const fs = require('fs');

let options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("privkey.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem")
  };
const app = require('express')(options);
const https = require('https').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(https,{origins:'*:*'});
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
const upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data

const sockets = {};

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

https.listen(3002, function () {
    console.log(chalk.yellow("Serviço rodando na porta 3002"));
});
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(chalk.green("Cliente Conectado"));
    sockets[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(chalk.red("Cliente Disconectado"));
        delete  sockets[socket.id];
    });
});

app.post('/atualizador', upload.array(), function (req, res) {
    _.each(sockets,function(socket,idSocket){
        console.log(idSocket);
        socket.emit('posicao',req.body);
    });
    res.send('Atualizador ON');
});
```

Client:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  localStorage.debug = '*';
  const socket = io.connect('https://localhost:3002/atualizador',{'forceNew': true});

  console.log(socket);

  socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket);
    socket.on('posicao', function (msg) {
      console.log("Ok");
      console.log(msg);
    });
    socket.on('teste', function (msg) {
      console.log("Ok");
      console.log(msg);
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Try removing "/atualizador" from your io.connect(...) call.

Comment: Yep, you're trying to connect your socket.io client to an express post route for some reason.